# Duda con método en MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

Tengo un problema, trato de cargar datos mediante el siguiente método pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ')'.
```

El método es el siguiente:

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> pdfDatos(float titulo, float? cuotas){
            List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadena");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT apellido, nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual, " +
                "planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo, max(Cuota) as cuota " +
                "FROM V_CuetaWeb " +
                "WHERE titulo IN ("+titulo+ ") AND cuota IN (" + cuotas + ") " +
                "GROUP BY apellido, nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual," +
                "planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()) {
                string apellido = dr["apellido"].ToString();
                string nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                string domicilio =dr["domicilio"].ToString();
                string barrio = dr["barrio"].ToString();
                string localidad = dr["localidad"].ToString();
                string tel = dr["telefono"].ToString();
                string celular = dr["celular"].ToString();
                string descpla = dr["descplanactual"].ToString();
                float plana = Convert.ToSingle(dr["PlanAntes"]);
                float vanom = Convert.ToSingle(dr["ValNom"]);
                int monto = Convert.ToInt32(dr["monto"]);
                string acid = dr["acidzona"].ToString();
                string cobrador = dr["cobrador"].ToString();
                string codigo = dr["codigo"].ToString();
                float tti = Convert.ToSingle(dr["titulo"]);
                float sorteo = Convert.ToSingle(dr["sorteo"]);
                float cuota = Convert.ToSingle(dr["cuota"]);
                ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(apellido, nombre, domicilio, barrio, localidad, tel, celular, descpla, 
                    plana, vanom, monto, acid, cobrador, codigo, tti, sorteo, cuota);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return salida;
        }
```

¿Alguno ve el error? Dice que está cerca de la cláusula GROUP By pero yo no veo el error.

Comment: prueba a dejar solo `GROUP BY apellido` en la consulta, y mira a ver que te dice (vamos, quita el resto de campos). Aunque tiene mas pinta de que la variable cuotas sea nula en algun caso y la consulta tenga `cuota IN ()`

Comment: Como dice @Jakala, el problema está en la variable `float? cuotas`. Al ser "nullable" seguramente te está llegando a `null` y se traduce a `cuota IN ()`.

Comment: porque usas IN con datos del tipo numerico? eso no es correcto

Comment: @Leandro Tuttini: utilizar `IN` para comparar un único solo valor del tipo `float` no es una opción correcta, pero ahí no está el error.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta pero si es un solo valor porque no comparalo con `=` asignando el valor por parametro en lugar de concatenarlo en el string

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, tienes toda la razón, pero digo, que ahí no está el error `Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ')'`según la pregunta del usuario. El problema es retornar valores NULL en `float? cuotas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu codigo deberia ser algo como el siguiente

```
string query = @"SELECT apellido, nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual, 
                planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo, max(Cuota) as cuota 
                FROM V_CuetaWeb 
                WHERE titulo = @titulo AND ((@cuotas IS NULL) OR (cuota = @cuotas))
                GROUP BY apellido, nombre,domicilio, barrio, localidad, telefono,celular, descplanactual,
                planantes, valnom,monto,acidzona, cobrador, codigo, titulo, sorteo";


SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", titulo);

if(cuotas.HasValue)
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuotas", cuotas);
else
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuotas", DBNull.Value);

SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
```

Usas parametros y puedes asignar un valor que puede ser opcional aplicando un filtro condicional usando `DBNull.Value` y evaluando el valor en la query

Comment: Sería mejor validar si los parámetros tienen valor en el código y con base en eso se incluye la condición en la consulta o no. Así se pueden conseguir planes de ejecución óptimos. También es recomendable evitar usar AddWithValue y en su lugar definir bien el tipo de dato para evitar conversiones a tipos de datos indeseados.

Comment: porque armar el query dinamico si se puede hacer condicional pasando o no el valor, ademas la conversion de datos es directa si se asigna un tipo que concuerda, si el campo en la db es decimal y se pasa un valor numerico en el parametro la conversion no deberia tener problemas

Comment: Te dejo un artículo en inglés que habla sobre ese tema escrito por una de las mejores profesionales de SQL Server a nivel mundial. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Comment: Por otro lado, AddWithValue funciona bien en la mayoría de los casos, el problema es cuando no lo hace y genera una conversión implicita en una columna que hace que se tenga que leer la tabla entera en vez de poder usar un índice adecuado.

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena porque utiliza parámetros, pero podría ser mejor siguiendo mejores prácticas.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido bastante

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a redefinir el método `pdfDatos()` de la siguiente manera:

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> pdfDatos(float titulo, float cuotas)
```

sin la **`?`** en la variable **`float? cuotas`**. Si te da un error diferente (*algo como no se permiten valores nulos...*), es que la variable **cuotas** está llegando a **NULL**.

Comprueba que la variable **cuotas** no sea **NULL** **antes o después** de llamar al método `pdfDatos()`.